# How would I code this for wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello I am fairly new to wordpress.

I was wondering if you guys have any idea on how to display post from wordpress and tweets
all in the same 'loop'.

I know It is possible using a if statement that displays a tweet ever nth-wordpress post. But I would like for both the tweets and the posts to be displayed by date in the same page. any ideas?

so far this is what my page looks like

```
<?php 
get_header();

if(have_posts()) {
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();

        $post_link = get_permalink(get_the_ID());
        //($beforeString, $afterString, T/F)
        //T/F retun in html-T or in php-F
        the_title('<h1><a href="'.$post_link.'">', '</a></h1>');
        the_content('<p>', '<p>');
        //echo <a href="get_permalink()" 
    }
}
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: You could use a plugin to upload twitts to your wp database

Comment: got any suggestions for plugins?

Comment: I'm using really-simple-twitter-feed-widget --> [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-twitter-feed-widget/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to get both sources into one array, then sort it and print it out:

```
<?php 
get_header();

//define array
$entrys=array();

//get wp-posts
if(have_posts()) {
    while(have_posts()) {
      the_post();

      $timestamp=//timestamp of post
      $entries[$timestamp]=array(
        'link'=>get_permalink(get_the_ID()),
        'title'=>get_the_title(get_the_ID()),
        'content'=>get_the_content()
      );
    }
}

//insert the twitter-data into the same array here

//sort array
ksort($entries);

//print array
foreach($entries as $e){
  echo '<div class="entry"><h1><a href="'.$e['link'].'">'.$e['title'].'</a></h1>';
  echo '<p>'.$e['content'].'</p>';
  echo '<a href="'.$e['link'].'">Link</a></div>';
}
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: functions the_content and the_title displays values. they don't return values.